# Why is the std::equal template parametrized by two classes?

Tags: c++

I am studying C++ using Accelerated C++ by Andrew Koenig and Barbara E. Moo. In exercises 8-2 the authors ask us to implement some library algorithms, among them equal.

Here's what I wrote:

```
template <class In>
bool my_equal(In b,In e,In d)
{
    for (;b!=e;++b,++d)
        if (*b!=*d) return false;
    return true;
}
```

When I check against implementations, I find mine almost identical, except everywhere they use a different class to parametrize b,e and d. Can anyone explain why this is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two template iterator types so that it's possible to compare elements from different containers even when the elements are the same. For example in the simplest case comparing a `std::vector<int>` with `std::deque<int>` wouldn't work with a single iterator type while with two iterator types it would allow you to compare the sequences of `int` with no extra logic needed.

Answer (score 2):

Counter example:

```
struct foo {};
struct bar {
    operator==(const foo&) { return false; }
    operator!=(const foo&) { return true; }
};
```

With the standard algorithm you can check if `bar`s are equal to a `foo`, you cannot do that with your version.

Also when you compare elements in different types of containers the two types differ. In general the standard library tries to be as generic as possible. For the standard version of `std::equal`, all that is required is that you can dereference the iterators and then compare the elements. What actually is the type of iterators or elements isnt important as long as the elements can be compared.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<T>::iterator` is a different type to `std::set<T>::iterator`, but it'd be really annoying if you couldn't call `equal` with a mix of them.

Even more so `std::vector<T>::iterator` and `std::vector<T>::const_iterator`.